# MTKView, why is the color different from CAMetalLayer to screenshot?

Tags: xcode, macos, metal

I found out the color of CAMetalLayer (export from Xcode) and MTKView on screen looks very different, I am using `RGBA16Float`. What is the possible reason? How to make sure they have the same color?

[image: CAMetalLayer]

[image: MTKView screenshot]

Comment: You're going to have to show how you created and configured the `MTKView` and `CAMetalLayer` and what their various properties defaulted to.

Comment: Please check your isOpaque property of both `CAMetalLayer` and `MTKView`

Comment: @KenThomases It's only a simple MTKView created with `DefaultDevice` and `Default ColorSpace`, then `RGBA16Float` colorPixelFormat. Nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a gamma correction issue. Xcode is probably using a linear light color space during export whereas the `MTKView` uses the sRGB gamma curve when displaying on the screen.

Comment: Hi, are there any document mentioned Xcode will change color while exporting CAMetalLayer or Texture under GPU capture debug session?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I was just making assumptions based on the look of your example images. It really looks like different gamma curves.

Comment: Maybe MTKView did some auto color correction for the display's native color space. I didn't see too much discussion on that. I guess there might be a way to tell the API which color space the buffer has, then which color space the View should try to interpret.

Comment: I saw the MTKView has both kCGColorSpaceSRGB and kCGColorSpaceLinearSRGB. It's very confusing, because I think sRGB is already in non-linear space.